# Make fix size round button as image in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I am developing an application in which I need to round button as image (as I uploaded).[image]

It Show two corner are straight and the rest is in round shape. I tried with`mybutton.layer.cornerRadius` but make round whole image. I also tried to just make custom button but it leave extra space in button around image i need to fix size button as image show.
Please help me. Thanks in advance. Happy Day.

Comment: Try [this](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/) or [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.ro/2010/03/improved-irregular-shape-uibutton.html). Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one good tutorial on this:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html

you can download code from here

https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

An alternate but not really a good one first add an imageView add this particular image over it than add an custom invisible button over the image by adjusting size of the button it will not cover the whole image though but still it will work fine...actually i did use this approach in one of my app :p

Comment: sorry naveen, as i mentioned i need fix size button according to your logic it leave space of button around imaged.

Comment: @Naveen:By doing this, you may not get default button tap effect.

Comment: @spaleja i did get the default button tap effect

Comment: @josh it will not leave space of button aroung the image. The button will be inside the image, but it will not cover all part of image

Answer (score 1):

[`OBShapedButton`](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-non-rectangular-button-shapes.html) might help. It's an open source UIButton subclass optimized for non-rectangular button shapes. If it still doesn't work, making your own buttons isn't that difficult either. Use a `UIView` and handle touches within the view. For eg, in `touchesMoved:`, set the active image and in `touchesEnded:`, handle the click event!