# Display UIButtons in circular formatin ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

How we can display UIButtons in circular format so that when we click a
particular `UIButton` it will move to middle position?

[image: circular buttons]

Comment: Trigonometry, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creat buttons:

```
double perAngle = 2 * M_PI / BUTTONS_COUNT;

for (int i = 0; i < BUTTONS_COUNT; i++) {
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sin(perAngle * i) + basePoint.x, cos(perAngle * i) + basePoint.y, yourWidth, yourHeight)];

    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(moveButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [yourView addSubView:btn];
}
```

Move button:

```
- (void)moveButton:(UIButton *)btn
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        btn.center = basePoint;
    }];
}
```

the `basePoint` is your circulars center point. It is just a demo code , and you should handle the moveback , and exception and so on.

PS: This code is a whole circular , and if yours is a half circular , you should calc the angle by your self , it is easy

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `touch recognition gesture` or you can simply put custom that `UIImage` and over that few custom `UIButton` with **clearcolor** background.

And for that **center image**, you can simply change **image** in your `UIImageView` according to the **selected** button.

**EDIT:**

**Solution 2:**

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

Look at this post also.
[Make fix size round button as image in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431983/make-fix-size-round-button-as-image-in-iphone-sdk)

Comment: You cannot? Huh? How about `button.frame = CGRectMake(cos(phi) * R, sin(phi) * R, width, height);`?

Comment: @H2CO3 can you give me frame for this? I tried `button.frame = CGRectMake(cos(30) * 70, sin(30) * 70, 140, 140);` It's still rectangle. Even I would love to know if we can do this.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for telling :) . Even i gained some knowledge from this. :)

Comment: @HinataHyuga: Create a UIButton with type custom and add a circular background image

Comment: @HinataHyuga I'm not talking about making the button have a circle shape. I was referring to a method for placing them on a circular path.

Comment: @MidhunMP: naaa that won't work.. you will be able to click on edges

Comment: @CrimeMasterGOGO: No. Please read carefully. I'm saying to add circular image on UIButton whose type is custom. It will be in circular shape. I had done it before.